# Easiest way to parse "querystring" formatted data

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string, postdata

With the following code:

```
string q = "userID=16555&gameID=60&score=4542.122&time=343114";
```

What would be the easiest way to parse the values, preferably without writing my own parser?  I'm looking for something with the same functionality as `Request.querystring["gameID"]`.

Answer (score 89):

Pretty easy... use the [HttpUtility.ParseQueryString method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.parsequerystring).

Untested, but this should work:

```
var qs = "userID=16555&gameID=60&score=4542.122&time=343114";
var parsed = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(qs);
var userId = parsed["userID"]; 
//  ^^^^^^ Should be "16555".  Note this will be a string of course.
```

Comment: Thanks!  Looks good, I'm having trouble decoding the horrible example they provided on the MSDN page though, once I have `var q = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString("?userID=16555&gameID=60&score=4542.122&time=343114");` how do I retrieve a specific value?

Comment: I can't find System.Net.HttpUtility net Core 1.0 framework

Comment: Seems like they removed it. Reference the answer here for a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29992848/parse-and-modify-a-query-string-in-net-core

Comment: The [Nancy](http://nancyfx.org/) library also includes `Nancy.Helpers.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString`.

Comment: Note that `ParseQueryString` fails is there is more than 1024 key-value pairs in the string.

Comment: @GSerg if you’ve got 1025 keys in a query string, I’d argue that you’ve got bigger problems 

Comment: @ChrisShain Well, there is e.g. one Paypal API that returns transactions data as a huge url-encoded string of key-value pairs. It easily exceeds 1024.

Answer (score 23):

You can do it  with linq like this.

```
string query = "id=3123123&userId=44423&format=json";

Dictionary<string,string> dicQueryString = 
        query.Split('&')
             .ToDictionary(c => c.Split('=')[0],
                           c => Uri.UnescapeDataString(c.Split('=')[1]));

string userId = dicQueryString["userID"];
```

**Edit**

If you can use [HttpUtility.ParseQueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx) then it will be a lot more straight forward and it wont be case-sensitive as in case of LinQ.

Comment: That works in this specific case, but it's not a generic solution because it doesn't do percent-decoding.

Comment: Right @Francis Avila, then it will need more modification in query.

Comment: This is a good solution if you need to parse query strings outside of the System.Web context.

Comment: This preserves case, unlike ParseQueryString.

Comment: And what happens when you have a query string like `a=1&a=2&a=3`? That is valid, as is `a=1;a=2;a=3`. Use `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString`. It handles these and other oddities.

Comment: I came here because HttpUtility.ParseQueryString() performed the decoding. this solution here works for me.

Comment: @JimMischel to `.ToLookup` rather than `.ToDictionary` to handle "duplicate keys"

Answer (score 7):

As has been mentioned in each of the previous answers, if you are in a context where you can add a dependency to the System.Web library, using [HttpUtility.ParseQueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx) makes sense.  (For reference, the relevant source can be found in the [Microsoft Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.web/HttpValueCollection.cs,222f9a1bfd1f9a98,references)).  However, if this is not possible, I would like to propose the following modification to [Adil's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11957114/1603383) answer which accounts for many of the concerns addressed in the comments (such as case sensitivity and duplicate keys):

```
var q = "userID=16555&gameID=60&score=4542.122&time=343114";
var parsed = q.TrimStart('?')
    .Split(new[] { '&' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(k => k.Split('='))
    .Where(k => k.Length == 2)
    .ToLookup(a => a[0], a => Uri.UnescapeDataString(a[1])
      , StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
var userId = parsed["userID"].FirstOrDefault();
var time = parsed["TIME"].Select(v => (int?)int.Parse(v)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Ignores single item arguments, which can sometimes also appear: `arg1&arg2&arg3`

Answer (score 5):

If you want to avoid the dependency on System.Web that is required to use [HttpUtility.ParseQueryString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx), you could use the `Uri` extension method `ParseQueryString` found in `System.Net.Http`.

Note that you have to convert the response body to a valid `Uri` so that `ParseQueryString` works.

Please also note in the MSDN document, this method is an extension method for the Uri class, so you need reference the assembly System.Net.Http.Formatting (in System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll). I tried installed it by the nuget package with the name "System.Net.Http.Formatting", and it works fine.

```
string body = "value1=randomvalue1&value2=randomValue2";

// "http://localhost/query?" is added to the string "body" in order to create a valid Uri.
string urlBody = "http://localhost/query?" + body;
NameValueCollection coll = new Uri(urlBody).ParseQueryString();
```

Comment: Not sure this works...Uri doesn't have a ParseQueryString method attached to it when I try this, my code: 
    

var collection = new System.Uri(url).ParseQueryString();

Comment: @TrevorHart Did you make sure to add a reference to System.Net.Http and to add the System.Net.Http namespace?

Comment: I did, I ended up just writing my own parser.

Answer (score 4):

How is this

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

// query example
//   "name1=value1&name2=value2&name3=value3"
//   "?name1=value1&name2=value2&name3=value3"
private Dictionary<string, string> ParseQuery(string query)
{
    var dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    var reg = new Regex("(?:[?&]|^)([^&]+)=([^&]*)");
    var matches = reg.Matches(query);
    foreach (Match match in matches) {
        dic[match.Groups[1].Value] = Uri.UnescapeDataString(match.Groups[2].Value);
    }
    return dic;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! Does it support single item arguments, as metioned by @jsuddsjr 's comment above?  _Ignores single item arguments, which can sometimes also appear: `arg1&arg2&arg3`_

Answer (score 3):

For .NET Core there is [Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.QueryHelpers.ParseQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.webutilities.queryhelpers.parsequery?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

```cs
var queryString = QueryHelpers.ParseQuery("?param1=value");
var queryParamValue = queryString["param1"];
```

Code snippet modified from [trackjs.com](https://trackjs.com/blog/query-string-parsing/):

Answer (score 1):

System.Net.Http ParseQueryString extension method worked for me. I'm using OData query options and trying to parse out some custom parameters.

```
options.Request.RequestUri.ParseQueryString();
```

Seems to give me what I need.

Answer (score 0):

HttpUtility.ParseQueryString will work as long as you are in a web app or don't mind including a dependency on System.Web. Another way to do this is:

```
// NameValueCollection nameValueCollection = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString);

NameValueCollection nameValueCollection = new NameValueCollection();
string[] querySegments = queryString.Split('&');
foreach(string segment in querySegments)
{
   string[] parts = segment.Split('=');
   if (parts.Length > 0)
   {
      string key = parts[0].Trim(new char[] { '?', ' ' });
      string val = parts[1].Trim();

      nameValueCollection.Add(key, val);
   }
}
```