# Separate values from a string

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a string, with data as shown below. How I read separately each property values.

ie  PCIaaS_CardId=value;
    BillingFirstName=value;

> PCIaaS_CardId=value&BillingFirstName=value&BillingLastName=value&BillingCompanyNamevalues=&BillingAddress1=value&BillingAddress2=values&BillingCity=value

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. I assume the second line is an example of a string to be parsed? Is this a querystring from a URL, or does it just happen to have same/similar format?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That looks like a HTTP query string, for which you can use [HttpUtility.ParseQueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks CompuChip... :). You give a great thread. I found a similar question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11956948/easiest-way-to-parse-querystring-formatted-data

Answer (score 1):

```
var propertyParts = yourString.Split('&');
foreach (var propertyStr in propertyParts)
{
    var keyValue = propertyParts.Split('=');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert string to dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, string> values = 
    str.Split('&').Select(s => s.Split('=')).ToDictionary(a => a[0], a => a[1]);
```

Then getting value by key will look like:

```
string firstName = values["FirstName"];
```

Answer (score 0):

`string[] abc = "value&BillingFirstName=value&BillingLastName=value&BillingCompanyNamevalues=&BillingAddress1=value&BillingAddress2=values&BillingCity=value".Split(new char[] { '&' });`

Then you can access it by abc[index]

OR

`string[] abc = yourString.Split(new char[] { '&' });`