# How can I pick out a number from a string in C#

Tags: c#

I have this string:

```
http://www.edrdg.org/jmdictdb/cgi-bin/edform.py?svc=jmdict&amp;sid=&amp;q=1007040&amp;a=2
```

How can I pick out the number between "q=" and "&amp" as an integer?

So in this case I want to get the number: 1007040

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734116/find-and-extract-a-number-from-a-string

Comment: `string result = Regex.Match(source, @"q\s*=\s*(?<value>[0-9]+)").Groups["value"].Value;`

Comment: I wouldn't look at it like getting a number from a string, instead I'd look at it like [parsing a query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11956948/easiest-way-to-parse-querystring-formatted-data)

Comment: This is a URI. Don't attempt to parse it manually. Instead, use the framework's built in tools to do that.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/le1Xec

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you're actually doing is parsing a URI - so you can use the .Net library to do this properly as follows:

```
var str   = "http://www.edrdg.org/jmdictdb/cgi-bin/edform.py?svc=jmdict&amp;sid=&amp;q=1007040&amp;a=2";
var uri   = new Uri(str);
var query = uri.Query;
var dict  = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(query);

Console.WriteLine(dict["amp;q"]); // Outputs 1007040
```

If you want the numeric string as an integer then you'd need to parse it:

```
int number = int.Parse(dict["amp;q"]);
```

Comment: Canonical [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/659887/1997232).

Answer (score 1):

Consider using regular expressions

```
String str = "http://www.edrdg.org/jmdictdb/cgi-bin/edform.py?svc=jmdict&amp;sid=&amp;q=1007040&amp;a=2";

Match match = Regex.Match(str, @"q=\d+&amp");

if (match.Success)
{
    string resultStr = match.Value.Replace("q=", String.Empty).Replace("&amp", String.Empty);
    int.TryParse(resultStr, out int result); // result = 1007040
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want a query parameter for a uri that's html encoded. You could do:

```
Uri uri = new Uri(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("http://www.edrdg.org/jmdictdb/cgi-bin/edform.py?svc=jmdict&amp;sid=&amp;q=1007040&amp;a=2"));
string q = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query).Get("q");
int qint = int.Parse(q);
```

Answer (score 1):

A regex approach using groups:

```
public int GetInt(string str)
{
    var match = Regex.Match(str,@"q=(\d*)&amp");
    return int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Absolutely no error checking in that!