# Move string into a Collection

Tags: vb.net

I'm receiving post data on the server-side which resembles a querystring:

```
type=subscribe&fired_at=2021-07-16 07:51:09&data[id]=ebdc32dce6&data[email]=xyz@fakeemail.com&data[email_type]=html&data[ip_opt]=110.20.71.126&data[ip_signup]=110.100.22.217&data[web_id]=566760869&data[merges][EMAIL]=xyz@fakeemail.com.com&data[merges][FNAME]=&data[merges][LNAME]=&data[merges][ADDRESS]=&data[merges][PHONE]=&data[merges][BIRTHDAY]=&data[list_id]=e971d14
```

The parameters are unknown so I'm looking for a dynamic solution. Note, the "data" parameter is actually an array of sorts.

I'd love to be able to retrieve key fields like:

```
Dim id as String = ParamList( "id" )
Dim email as String = ParamList( "email" )
```

What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you seen [Easiest way to parse “querystring” formatted data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11956948/easiest-way-to-parse-querystring-formatted-data)? It looks like some further parsing of the keys will be needed for the example in the question.

Answer (score 1):

As Andrew has indicated:

```
Dim s = "type=subscribe&fired_at=2021-07-16 07:51:09&data[id]=ebdc32dce6&data[email]=xyz@fakeemail.com&data[email_type]=html&data[ip_opt]=110.20.71.126&data[ip_signup]=110.100.22.217&data[web_id]=566760869&data[merges][EMAIL]=xyz@fakeemail.com.com&data[merges][FNAME]=&data[merges][LNAME]=&data[merges][ADDRESS]=&data[merges][PHONE]=&data[merges][BIRTHDAY]=&data[list_id]=e971d14"
Dim c = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(s); 'need to Imports System.Web
```

Note that the parser doesn't care about the `data[...]` as being "a dictionary" etc - you say you just want to write the `...` but the whole key includes the `data[` and `]` too.. This means you either :

```
Dim id = c( "data[id]" )
Dim email = c( "data[email]" )
```

Or you could generate a new collection, such as a dictionary, with altered keys:

```
Dim d = c.Keys.Cast<string>().ToDictionary( _
    Function(k) k.Split("[]".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Last(), _
    Function(k) c(k) _
)
```

This can be indexed like

```
Dim id = d("id")
Dim bd = d("BIRTHDAY")
```

But be careful with ToDictionary: the keys need to be unique. If they aren't, you cna use ToLookup but note that the entries in the "dictionary" will then be enumerables (lists of values) not single values

Comment: The likes of `data[merges][FNAME]` in conjunction with "The parameters are unknown" had me concerned.

Comment: I suppose if it's all "stringly typed" then the user could be prompted for it :D